# How do I query parse for this?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

so I am passing a sender Id which is the same as a parse objectId. My whole idea is that I am trying to match up messages with appropriate profile pictures.
I am trying to go to my user object and find the line in object id that === to my senderId and then I need to return the picture attribute value from that row. object.get(picture) I presume? is this right? I am not getting the appropriate output. picture and objectId are both attributes of my table.

```
//var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse._User);

query.equalTo("objectId", senderId);
query.find({
    success: function(object) {
        var senderPicture = object.get('picture');
        $('<img src="'+ senderPicture +'">').load(function() {
            $(this).width("150").height("150").appendTo('#MenuBackground');
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try using `var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User)` instead

Comment: As Skelly said, use Parse.User. Anyway the Parse User Class is named "_User" not "User".

Comment: Gotcha! I am at my workstation at this very moment, but I adjusted my post. Is my correction in my code what you mean?

Comment: i feel like something isnt quite right with the object.get. picture and objectId are both columns and I am just trying to select picture where senderId==objectId from my user